# Xcode workspace, project and product structure for arduino projects

Tags: xcode, project, product, workspace, arduino-ide

I want to use Xcode instead of the ArduinoIDE.  I don't need Xcode to build, but I would like to use it for file grouping and source control.  This is an example of the structure that I want.  You can see that I'm trying to reuse libraries (L3) in more than one **product**.  It doesn't matter to me whether there is one source control repository that contains all three products below, or three repositories.

```
myWorkspace

  Project 1: Custom Libraries (under source control)
    File L1
    File L2
    File L3

  Project 2: Product ABC (under source control)
    File A
    File B
    File C  
    File L1 (reference to Project1/FileL1, not a copy)
    File L3 (reference to Project1/FileL3, not a copy)

  Project 3: Product DEF (under source control)
    File D
    File E
    File F  
    File L2 (reference to Project1/FileL2, not a copy)
    File L3 (reference to Project1/FileL3, not a copy)
```

Am I conceptualizing this incorrectly?  I can't seem to get concurrent "non-build" projects to exist in a workspace simultaneously.  I tried "Other" project type and "External Build" project type.

Comment: what exactly is that you can't do?

Comment: "I can't seem to get concurrent "non-build" projects to exist in a workspace simultaneously."